Is ordinal arithmetic defined in $\textbf{ZFC}$?
Question 1: can ordinal arithmetic be defined in $\text{ZFC}$?
My guess would be no, as it is a function $\text{Ord}^2\to\text{Ord}$ and $\text{Ord}$ is not a set to begin with.
Question 2: can ordinal arithmetic up to any fixed ordinal $\gamma$ be defined in $\text{ZFC}$? That is, to define $\alpha + \beta$ for all ordinals $\alpha,\beta < \gamma$.
Here my guess is yes. It is certainly possible with small ordinals e.g. $\omega + 5$. When trying to define it, I stumble upon the following difficulty: the definition of ordinal addition (in my textbook: Sech's Set Theory) uses Transfinite Recursion:

Theorem 2.15 (Transfinite Recursion). Let $G$ be a function (on $V$), then (2.6) below defines a unique function $F$ on $\text{Ord}$ such that
$$
F(\alpha) = G(F \upharpoonright \alpha)
$$
for each $\alpha$.
In other words, if we let $a_\alpha = F(\alpha)$, then for each $\alpha$,
$$
a_\alpha = G(\langle a_\xi : \xi < \alpha \rangle).
$$

where $V$ is the universal set $\{x : x = x\}$, $\text{Ord}$ is the class of ordinals, and $F \upharpoonright \alpha$ is $F$ restricted to $\alpha$.
As such, the definition of ordinal arithmetic uses a function $G:V\to V$ which lies 'outside' of $\text{ZFC}$, as we cannot even speak of $V$ in the theory.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ every object is a set, and there are no classes, this is correct. One can however talk about definable classes with some abuse of notation. We say that $\mathbf M$ is a definable class if there exists a formula $\varphi$ with $\mathbf M=\{x\mid \varphi(x)\}$, so for example $V$ is defined by the formula $\varphi(x)$ stating $x=x$, while $\mathsf{Ord}$ is defined by the formula $\psi(x)$ stating "$x$ is transitive and totally ordered by $\in$" (which I am now stating in a mix of english and formal language, but which can be reformulated in a completely formal way). By using formulas with more variables one can talk about definable subclasses of $V^2$ such as $\mathsf{Ord}\times\mathsf{Ord}$.
Now any statements such as "$\forall x\in\mathsf{Ord}\,\eta(x)$" where $\eta(x)$ is a formula can be reformulated as $\forall x(\psi(x)\rightarrow\eta(x))$, where $\psi(x)$ is the formula defining the class $\mathsf{Ord}$ from above.
Similarly one can talk about class functions $F\colon\mathbf{M}\to V$, such a class function is really a formula $\varphi(x,y)$ with the property that $\forall x\in\mathbf{M}\exists!y\,\varphi(x,y)$, so that we can informally say that $y=F(x)$ (note that this is done already in the axiom of replacement). Ordinal addition is now a definable function $\mathsf{Ord}\times\mathsf{Ord}\to\mathsf{Ord}$ in the sense that there exists a formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ such that $\forall x\forall y\in\mathsf{Ord}\exists!z\in\mathsf{Ord}\varphi(x,y,z)$, and given $x,y$ ordinals, this unique $z$ happens to be $x+y$.
The recursion theorem that you mentioned is one of the main tools to show that some class functions (such as ordinal addition) are indeed definable. Note that the recursion theorem itself is not really a statement of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but it is rather an infinite collection of theorems, one for every definable function, since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has no way of quantifying over class functions.
Regarding question 2 it is now easy to define addition up to a certain ordinal, say $\gamma$, take the class function $F\colon\mathsf{Ord}\times\mathsf{Ord}\to\mathsf{Ord}$ with $F(\alpha,\beta)=\alpha+\beta$ produced above and note that by the axiom of replacement $Y=F[\gamma\times\gamma]$ is a set. We can now define addition up to $\gamma$ to be the function associating to $(\alpha,\beta)\in\gamma^2$ the unique $\delta\in Y$ with $\delta=F(\alpha,\beta)$. A similar argument applies in general to definable class functions $F$, if you're only interested in them up to some bounded rank $\gamma$, you can intersect their domain with $V_\gamma$ and use replacement to show that the image of this cut off version of the domain is again a set.

This is a great answer, ang it goes above and beyond answering the first question! That being said, I don't think it answers the second question (although, correct me if I'm wrong)

@Sam sorry, I forgot about the second part, I'll edit my answer
